# Operation timed out PORT 22, on SSH access to AWS EC2. How to solve it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, timeout

I have a instance Linux in an EC2 service that was working before I changed the security group in order to accept HTTP port 80.

Before that change it was only port 22, SSH, we see in the picture below:
[image]

After I added HTTP I can't get access trough the terminal and get Time out operation error.[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: That change would not have caused this issue. Something else must have changed. Did you restart the instance or anything? Did you make any changes at all on the server itself?

Comment: I restarted. I found the issue. New ip. I was using old ip.

Comment: Yep if you stopped it, and then started it (not a reboot) then the public IP will change. You can attach an Elastic IP address to prevent that.

Comment: nice... post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stopped the instance, and then started it (not a reboot) then the public IP will change. You can attach an Elastic IP address to prevent that.

Comment: "attach an Elastic IP address" I feel this suggestion should come with disclaimer that you will be charged if instance is down. Some time people are sensitive for billing. I understand EIP cost is not too much and we don't know in this case OP running box for 24 hours are not, but someone who want to squeeze costs as much as possible, I feel this disclaimer adds more value to the answer.

Comment: That's a good point. I assumed the instance normally ran 24/7 since this was the first time the IP address change had been experienced.